# Missing Data with Row Number() in my results

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote some code to retrieve a Students Admission Information called ADMR Code ('IMMU','HST1','RCEC','TEST') - the code has no errors and produces a report.  The Report when validating the data has data missing from the report.  I am missing some of the data for the ADMR Code in the report - I have changed the values in the Row Number() function which changes the results but the results are still not correct.  The code reads a table that has multiple rows per student for each ADMR code...I wanted to NOT have multiple rows on my report but to put all of the ADMR codes in their own column per Student - Output Example:

```
Student_ID    IMMU         HST1       RCEC        TEST  
51738         08-JUN-09         
51811                      27-APR-17  27-APR-17     
51965         12-APR-17                           07-APR-17
```

Thank you in advance for any input

The Code is Below:

```
select admr_code.pidm,
max(case when admr_code.position = 1 and admr_code.admr = 'HST1' then admr_code.rec_date end)HST1,
max(case when admr_code.position = 2 and admr_code.admr = 'IMMU' then admr_code.rec_date end)IMMU,
max(case when admr_code.position = 3 and admr_code.admr = 'RCEC' then admr_code.rec_date end)RCEC,
max(case when admr_code.position = 4 and admr_code.admr = 'TEST' then admr_code.rec_date end)TEST
from 
(select 
sarchkl_pidm pidm,
sarchkl_term_code_entry term,
sarchkl_admr_code admr, 
sarchkl_receive_date rec_date,
row_number() over(partition by sarchkl_pidm order by sarchkl_pidm asc) position
from sarchkl  
where sarchkl_term_code_entry = '201750' and 
sarchkl_admr_code IN ('HST1','IMMU','RCEC','TEST')
)admr_code
Group By admr_code.pidm
order by admr_code.pidm
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you can provide some sample data.

Comment: is it possible each student in sarchkl may not have all 4 admr_codes? if so then the position you generate may vary by student.  Can you give sample data for a sarchkl student that isn't returning the expected results?

Comment: Yes that is correct - Students may have one, more then one, All, or no ADMR codes   As for the sample data I will try to post the data being pulled and a report sample.

Comment: I have 4 columns - ID, HST1, IMMU, RCEC, TEST - if they have a ADMR_Code (HST1, IMMU, RCEC, TEST) I put the Receive_Date in the corresponding column - by the ID.  Data Example per Student 51811- RCEC - 07/27/17 , Student 56565 - HST1 and RCEC both 07/01/17, and Student 105211 HST1, IMMU, and RCEC all 07/14/17 - Student 105211 is missing the RCEC Receive_date.  The Table when doing a check to the data Has a receive_date for RCEC but not pulling to the report - all other data is being pulled.

Comment: Why do you calculate the ROW_NUMBER? You got 4 known values, thus simply remove it and then the `admr_code.position = ...` from the CASE.

Comment: Use a PIVOT. Also, your ROW_NUMBER()...ORDER BY.... should be ordered by whatever criteria you need to put those in the order that the ADMR need?

Comment: Looking back at the given data (and catching up on the last 2 comments), I agree with dnoeth. Unless there is something else in the data that you haven't shown, it doesn't look like you need a ROW_NUMBER(). Just SELECT the records straight out and then PIVOT on the student ID.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Comment: My Goal was to create a single row for each student instead of having multiple rows per student - thus creating my 4 columns of the ADMR codes.  that makes alot of sense to not have the position number value - I will remove that and add the '...' and see what happens - Thank you I will let you know what happens.  I also will have to read on doing the pivot - not something that I used but it seems I should know...I think that is a cross-tab correct?  I will need to see the syntax.....Thanx also

Comment: I removed the position and re-ran the report - it worked beautifully...I verified the data and the data is spot on.  Thank you to all who took the time to answer my question and effort to relay such information to me.  Thanx again!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is T-SQL, but the PL-SQL syntax should be very similar. I don't have Oracle to test on right now.

A PIVOT will get you the dates you need under the columns you need without duplicates if there are multiple dates listed. In my test data, I added a dupe date row and some other bad data that should be excluded from the final query.

```
/* CTE for test data */
; WITH sarchkl AS (
     SELECT 51738 AS sarchkl_pidm, '201750' AS sarchkl_term_code_entry, 'IMMU' AS sarchkl_admr_code, '20090608' AS sarchkl_receive_date UNION ALL
     SELECT 51738 AS sarchkl_pidm, '201750' AS sarchkl_term_code_entry, 'IMMU' AS sarchkl_admr_code, '20001231' AS sarchkl_receive_date UNION ALL
     SELECT 51738 AS sarchkl_pidm, '201740' AS sarchkl_term_code_entry, 'IMMU' AS sarchkl_admr_code, '20090608' AS sarchkl_receive_date UNION ALL
     SELECT 51811 AS sarchkl_pidm, '201750' AS sarchkl_term_code_entry, 'HST1' AS sarchkl_admr_code, '20170427' AS sarchkl_receive_date UNION ALL
     SELECT 51811 AS sarchkl_pidm, '201750' AS sarchkl_term_code_entry, 'RCEC' AS sarchkl_admr_code, '20170427' AS sarchkl_receive_date UNION ALL
     SELECT 51965 AS sarchkl_pidm, '201750' AS sarchkl_term_code_entry, 'IMMU' AS sarchkl_admr_code, '20170412' AS sarchkl_receive_date UNION ALL
     SELECT 51965 AS sarchkl_pidm, '201750' AS sarchkl_term_code_entry, 'FAKE' AS sarchkl_admr_code, '20170101' AS sarchkl_receive_date UNION ALL
     SELECT 51965 AS sarchkl_pidm, '201750' AS sarchkl_term_code_entry, 'TEST' AS sarchkl_admr_code, '20170407' AS sarchkl_receive_date 
)

/* QUERY */    
SELECT b.sarchkl_pidm AS pidm, b.HST1, b.IMMU, b.RCEC, b.TEST
FROM (
    SELECT sarchkl_pidm, sarchkl_admr_code, sarchkl_receive_date
    FROM sarchkl
    WHERE sarchkl_term_code_entry = '201750'
        AND sarchkl_admr_code IN ('HST1','IMMU','RCEC','TEST')
) a PIVOT (
    max(sarchkl_receive_date)
    FOR sarchkl_admr_code
    IN (HST1,IMMU,RCEC,TEST)
) b
ORDER BY pidm
```

I added the aliases in the query to illustrate where the columns are coming from. PIVOTs will hurt your head if you think about them too much, but they are a great tool.